# debugging .a library with QtCreator

Tags: qt, debugging, qt5, qt-creator, static-libraries

I wrote a static library with qtcreator which has a `constructor` function.
i need to debug it.
Is it possible to debug a static library in QTCreator? How?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear enough but, generally it's not possible to debug a single library without any executable, you need a library testbed application. you have to write small test application which make calls to your library functions and so you can debug it.

You can write test application inside qt creator and debug it or debugging a third party application inside qt creator.

Also You library should be compiled with -g switch, in order to see interactive debugging on C++ codes.